# Smart Table not sorting properly

Tags: javascript, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat, smart-table

My column headers aren't sorting correctly with smart table. Instead of sorting individually they are all sorting together.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-sort="field" ng-repeat="field in stat.q">{{field}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Here is the javascript.

```
stat.q = ["Who is the coolest?", "What is your favorite color?", "Pick a movie", "Where do you want to go?", "test rating"];
```

Answer (score 3):

For usin ng-repeat you must put the braces around {{field}}:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th st-sort="{{field}}" ng-repeat="field in stat.q">{{field}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a `<tbody>` then use the ng-repeat on a `<tr>` element.

Example with source code is here:  http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-sort